# Is it safe to remove hibernate-validator dependency from starter-web?

Tags: spring-boot

I saw that spring-boot-starter-web includes this dependency that is about 1MB.
If I don't access to the database can I safely remove it? Isn't it already included in spring-data-jpa anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Validator does not necessarily have to do anything with a database. It is used for [Bean Validation](https://hibernate.org/validator/), e.g. it can also be used for validating incoming requests ([see this link](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/), if you're interested). If you do not need Bean Validation, you can safely remove it.

It's not included in spring-data-jpa at this point in time.